# How to retry the same search query for restaurants to get the next page of results from Google Map Api, using Retrofit and RxJava

Tags: java, android, google-maps, retrofit, rx-java2

I’m doing request to Google Map, to get a list of restaurants, using the Nearby Search Api.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby
The server sends its response through pages containing a maximum of 20 results.
If an extra page is available, the json next_page_token attribute is set, containing the value to be passed as a parameter to the next search.
Using retrofit and RxJava, I know how to do the first search, and get the next_page_token.
But I don’t know how to retry the same request.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
public Observable<PlaceNearbySearch> streamFetchRestaurants(String location, int radius, String type) {
// search for the list of restaurants
    RestoApi restoApi = RetrofitBuilder.getRetrofit().create(RestoApi.class);
        return restoApi.getRestoFirsttPage(location, radius, type, GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY) 
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
public Observable<PlaceDetail> streamFetchDetails(String placeId) {
// search details for each restaurants of the list
RestoApi restoApi = RetrofitBuilder.getRetrofit().create(RestoApi.class);
return restoApi.getPlaceDetails(placeId, GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

public Single<List<PlaceDetail>> streamFetchRestaurantDetails(String location, int radius, String type) {
// chains the 2 previous requests
    return streamFetchRestaurants(location, radius, type)
            .flatMapIterable(new Function<PlaceNearbySearch, List<PlaceNearbySearchPlace>>() {
                @Override
                public List<PlaceNearbySearchPlace> apply(PlaceNearbySearch placeNearbySearch) throws Exception {
                    // Is next_page_token set?
                    // In case it is, how would you query the next page??
                    Log.d(TAG, "apply: next_page_token: " + placeNearbySearch.getNext_page_token());
                    return placeNearbySearch.getResultSearches();

                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Function<PlaceNearbySearchPlace, Observable<PlaceDetail>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<PlaceDetail> apply(PlaceNearbySearchPlace placeNearbySearchPlace) throws Exception {
                    return streamFetchDetails(placeNearbySearchPlace.getPlaceId());
                }
            })
            .toList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}

private void test_streamFetchRestaurantDetails() throws InterruptedException {
// test method
    String location = "48.854685336064264, 2.3467574997969596";
    int radius = 1500;
    String type = "restaurant";
    callstreamFetchRestaurantDetails(location, radius, type);
}

private void callstreamFetchRestaurantDetails(String location, int radius, String type) {
    streamFetchRestaurantDetails(location, radius, type)
            .subscribe(new DisposableSingleObserver<List<PlaceDetail>>() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull List<PlaceDetail> placeDetails) {
                    // handle list of placeDetails
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onError: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "next_page_token" this will return you the next 20 results. If there are no more results available it will not send you the next_page_token. Check [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby#PlaceSearchPaging) document for usage of this token.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I know that! What I don't know is, how to use next_page_token in my code. I know I have to replay the search request, using the pagetoken parameter. What I don't know is,  how to replay the search request!

Comment: @user2072215 The way you have created getRestoFirsttPage() method create another method getNextPage() and pass the pagetoken and key as parameter in get request. The request will look the last request on this page.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby#PlaceSearchPaging

Comment: Ok, but getRestoFirsttPage will return immediately. Then when getNextPage is called, the first search is not completed, and the value of next_page_token has not been set. How will you start getNextPage only when first search has been completed?

Comment: @user2072215 once you have the first result show them to user and save the token then if user wants to see the next few results give them a way to initiate the next request like a next button once user wants to download the next 20 results use the previously saved token